# How to stub an instance variable in service initialize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a service which calls another ftp service which gets a file from the ftp sever and stores in a instance variable.

Now while testing the service I don't want to hit the ftp service, instead I want to pick the file from fixtures.

So, how can I stub the instance variable to pick the file from fixtures?

I tried below before_each method in Rspec test case, which didn't work.

```
  def set_scheme_details_file_path
    raw_file_path = '/spec/fixtures/backoffice_test_data/currentnav.ace'
    @scheme_details_file_path = File.join(Rails.root, raw_file_path)
  end
```

Service Initialize code which calls ftp service to get file object:

```
  class ImportServices::ImportSchemeDetail < BackOffice::ImportServices::Import
    def initialize(*args)
      @scheme_details_file_path = BackOffice::Util::Ftp.call(args[0])
      @scheme_details_set = []
      @result = {}
      @all_schemes = Scheme.generate_scheme_code_id_map
    end
```

Any help or suggestion will be helpful.
Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

```
allow(BackOffice::Util::Ftp).to receive(:call).and_return(some_path)
```

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks